# Why can't I post topics on a Forum?

Tags: forum

I recently installed the forum module on a site (currently running ee 2.5.2) and while the installation and set up went fine, any attempts to preview or post topics simply reloads the topic form page and does not successfully post the entry.

No code to post at this point but I would sure be interested in solving the problem of not being able to add entries.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the forum out of an EE template or it's normal install location? Is the forum online where we can see it? Any JS errors? Are you using a customized theme or the default theme?

Comment: I am running it out of its normal install location. It is visible online here: http://hpgresources.com/forums/. At this point I am using one of the default themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much to go on here... but a shot in the dark would be to take a look at your .htaccess file (if you have one) - I've seen issues like this when using mod_rewrite before.

Try removing your .htaccess file and accessing the forms with index.php in the URL.

Comment: Hi Philip, the .htaccess file was oversized with all kinds of irrelevant stuff from the previous developer. I simplified it down and now things are working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the latest version of ExpressionEngine with the latest version of the ExpressionEninge Forum module?

Make sure you have the latest and greatest version of each downloaded from ellislab.com and installed. If you are using an htaccess file temporarily remove it and run through the standard index.php url structure to see if you can pinpoint your issues.

Comment: Hi David, I am running ee 2.5.2 and the latest version of Forum.